# Grouping in kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid jQuery version and displaying the data using “group and aggregate” functions. The grouping is happening based on specific id(ex: StgId). There are 3 levels of sub groups are available.

The problem is, we need to show the value in a new column, against the Main Group level. We have the relation between that value and the grouping id(ex: StgId). We can not use the aggregate function for that showing value. We tried with Kendo Grid’s “groupFooterTemplate” and “groupHeaderTemplate” options.

The expected value is showing in 3rd sub group level. It is not showing in main group level.

Pleasee help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: It is hard to visualize what you are aiming to achieve. Can you show some picture or code and explain the problem pointing to the reference.

Comment: I have only 6 reputations now. Its not allowing me to add image